# Writing a command to a script file with proper quoting

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting

A situation that I've run into a few times: I have a shell function that does some setup and then invokes a more-or-less arbitrary command, like this:

```
setup_and_run() {
    some_setup_commands
    "$@"
}
```

I want to alter this function to also write a script file that I can use to re-run the command after doing the same setup. I can do the following, which works when there are no arguments with spaces or other weird stuff in the command:

```
setup_and_run() {
    some_setup_commands
    cat >>rerun.sh <<EOF
some_setup_commands
$@
EOF
    "$@"
}
```

Is there a standard way to alter this so that the script gets written with proper quoting, in general, even if some arguments have spaces or other special characters?

For example, with the second definition of `setup_and_run`, if I run

```
$ setup_and_run ls "my cat's \"password\""
my cat's "password"
```

then `rerun.sh` will contain

```
some_setup_commands
ls my cat's "password"
```

whereas I want it to contain something like

```
some_setup_commands
ls "my cat's \"password\""
```

or

```
some_setup_commands
ls my\ cat\'s\ \"password\"
```

or some such thing.

In a pinch I can outsource this to something like Python's [`shlex.quote()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote), but I'm looking for something that can be done in the shell itself if possible, or at least using a lighter-weight standard UNIX tool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In bash, ksh93 and zsh, you can use the `%q` escape for the [`printf` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-printf).

```
#!/bin/bash
# also works in ksh93, zsh
setup_and_run() {
    some_setup_commands
    cat >>rerun.sh <<EOF
some_setup_commands
$(printf '%q ' "$@")
EOF
    "$@"
}
```

In bash, you can use the `printf -v` to write the output to a variable rather than to standard output.

```
#!/bin/bash
printf -v cmd '%q ' "$@"
setup_and_run() {
    some_setup_commands
    cat >>rerun.sh <<EOF
some_setup_commands
$cmd
EOF
    "$@"
}
```

In zsh, there's a different method which is the `q` [parameter expansion flag](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags), followed by `j: :` to join the array elements with a space.

```
#!/bin/zsh
setup_and_run() {
    some_setup_commands
    cat >>rerun.sh <<EOF
some_setup_commands
${(j: :)${(q)@}}
EOF
    "$@"
}
```

In plain sh, it's more difficult. A reliable way to quote a word is to put single quotes around it, and replace each single quote inside by `'\''`. Making the replacement correctly is not very easy, involving either an external call to sed or a loop.

```
#!/bin/sh
quote_simple_command () {
  quoted=
  for raw in "$@"; do
    quoted="$quoted'"
    while case "$raw" in *\'*) true;; *) false;; esac; do
      quoted="$quoted${raw%%\'*}'\\''"
      raw="${raw#*\'}"
    done
    quoted="$quoted$raw' "
  done
  printf %s "${quoted% }"
}
setup_and_run() {
    some_setup_commands
    cat >>rerun.sh <<EOF
some_setup_commands
$(quote_simple_command "$@")
EOF
    "$@"
}
```

Comment: I see that `printf '%s\n' "'${somevar//\'/'\''}'"` doesn't work, but *why* doesn't it work?

Comment: @Wildcard, because you have a single-quoted string inside the `${...}` and you tried to use a backslash within it, which doesn't work. (Which technically means the shell is still expecting a `"`, a `}` _and_ a `"`. I think.) `"'${foo//\'/\'\\\'\'}'"` seems it would do what you want.

Comment: @ilkkachu, except that it doesn't.  I tried that already.  Bash's single quote handling in the replacement string of parameter expansion appears to be wildly erratic and insane.  ...further experimentation shows, it is actually consistent (sort of).  It interprets non-escaped single quotes as single quotes, *but* it preserves both escaped and non-escaped single quotes, *along with the escape character used on single quotes.*  Annoying.  Edit: Wait, no, it de-doubles the backslashes appearing within non-escaped single quotes, and does parameter expansion too.

Comment: @ilkkachu, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/410983/135943

Comment: @Wildcard I left a comment on your other question/answer, but for clarity for anyone else reading this comment chain: `q="abc'def'ghi"; echo "'${q//\'/\'\\\'\'}'"` does in fact echo the correctly escaped value `'abc'\''def'\''ghi'` for me in `bash`. **However** it fails in Busybox's `ash`, outputting `'abc\'\\'\'def\'\\'\'ghi'` instead. Even if you ignore the main portability issue with `${foo//bar/qux}` syntax (many bourne-like shells don't support it), the way such syntax combines with a wrapping of double-quotes is inconsistent between shells.

Comment: Actually, @Wildcard has identified a notable issue in the linked question's thread: older versions of `bash` until relatively recently were, in fact, behaving as my Busybox `ash` does. Sometime between versions 4.1-something and 4.3-something, `bash` changed how it parses `"'${foo//\'/\'\\\'\'}'"`.